# Reading shapes inside a group/container using aspose.diagram java

Tags: java, github, visio, aspose

I am trying to use the aspose.diagram API for Java to read my visio (vsdx) file and extract the information of shapes, stencils, connectors, etc. In examples/diagram/shapes when I try to run retrieveShapeInfo class of Java with a file specified in the code, it does not extract the information of the shapes present in the group/container.

Here is the link of the github repository I am using. 
https://github.com/aspose-diagram/Aspose.Diagram-for-Java
I am using com.aspose.diagram.examples/Shapes/RetriveShapeInfo java class from the repository.

[The image contains the diagram with a group. In the code, the shapes inside the group are not extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFIJg.png)

Here is my code snippet.

```html
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
 {
  // ExStart:RetrieveShapeInfo
  // The path to the documents directory.
  String dataDir = Utils.getSharedDataDir(RetrieveShapeInfo.class) + "Shapes/";

  // Load diagram
  //Diagram diagram = new Diagram(dataDir + "RetrieveShapeInfo.vsd");
  Diagram diagram = new Diagram(dataDir + "filename.vsdx");

  System.out.println(diagram.getPages().getPage(0).getShapes().getCount());
        //List<Shape> ignoredShapes = new List<Shape>();
  for (com.aspose.diagram.Shape shape : (Iterable<Shape>) diagram.getPages().getPage(0).getShapes())
  {

   // Display information about the shapes
   System.out.println("\nShape ID : " + shape.getID());
   System.out.println("Name : " + shape.getName());
   if(shape.getMaster() != null)
       System.out.println("Master Shape : " + shape.getMaster().getName());

   // ExEnd:RetrieveShapeInfo
  }
```

Comment: I don't know about aspose, but it looks like you have grouped flowchart shapes. You will have to traverse shapes inside of that group and ask each one for shape Info. This could go on infinitely (but probably won't). I see a check for if-shape-has-master. That is a good clue as to whether a shape is a "top-level" shape, and likely to contain Shape Data (if that's what you're searching for). As you look for shapes within groups within groups, if a shape has a master, it is likely a good place to stop. It very unlikely that a user will drop a master, then open it up and add masters inside of it!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to parse through each shape in the group. Here is the snippet.

```
// for group shapes
            if(shape.getType()==TypeValue.GROUP)
                for (com.aspose.diagram.Shape subshape : (Iterable<com.aspose.diagram.Shape>) shape.getShapes()) {
                    System.out.println("\nParent Shape ID : " + shape.getID());
                    System.out.println("Parent Name : " + shape.getName());
                    System.out.println("\nShape ID : " + subshape.getID());
                    System.out.println("Name : " + subshape.getName());

                    //System.out.println(shape.getShapes().getCount());
                    if (subshape.getText().getValue().getText() != "") {
                        txt = (subshape.getText().getValue().getText().replaceAll("\\<.*?>", ""));
                        System.out.println("Text from shape added : " + txt);
                        txt += txt;
                    }
```

This code snippet parses through the group shapes and returns the parent id, name and child shape id and name along with the text of the shape. However the snippet is not able to extract all the shapes inside the container/group.

Here is the output.
Shape ID : 1
Name : Square.1
Text from shape added: ​Amazon route 53

Shape ID : 2
Name : Square.2
Text from shape added: ​AWS WAF

Shape ID : 3
Name : Square.3
Text from shape added: CloudFRont Distribution​

Shape ID : 4
Name : Square.4
Text from shape added: ​S3

Shape ID : 5
Name : Square.5
Text from shape added: ​AWS cognito user pool

Shape ID : 6
Name : Square.6
Text from shape added: ​AWS quicksight

Shape ID : 9
Name : Circle.9
Text from shape added: ​AWS aurora

Shape ID : 10
Name : Circle.10
Text from shape added: ​Redshift

Shape ID : 15
Name : Hexagon.15
Text from shape added: ​Dynamo db

Shape ID : 16
Name : Hexagon.16
Text from shape added: ​Amazon Athena

Shape ID : 36
Name : 
Text from shape added: ​logic tier

Parent Shape ID : 36
Parent Name :

Shape ID : 18
Name : Circle.18
Text from shape added : ​cloudWatch

Parent Shape ID : 36
Parent Name :

Shape ID : 35
Name :